# how to download file using Flutter with Laravel

Tags: android, ios, laravel, flutter, dio

I am trying to download the the excel file from laravel backend through my flutter app. I have used dio package to download that file. but I am getting this error while downloading the app.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [405]
E/flutter (24963): Source stack:
```

**FLUTTER CODE **

```
void downloaddd() async {
    String name = "Excel-of-salaries";
    String path = await _getFilePath(name);
    String url =
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${widget.masterID}";
    var data = await dio.download(url, path, data: {
      "id": 1,
    });
    print(data);
  }
```

**LARAVEL CODE**

```
class SalaryExportsController extends Controller
{
    public function export(Request $request, $id)
    {
        return Excel::download(new SalaryExports($request, $id), 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
Route::post('/xxxxxxxxxx/{id}', [SalaryExportsController::class, 'export']);
```

Comment: Http status error [405] said: Method Not Allowed, probably it's because of your flutter download code, try dio.post(), maybe it works

Comment: but i want to download that file sir . @SaeedGhasemi

Comment: PK getting this as a response sir....

Comment: also you have to define a path for downloaded file

Comment: Yes i have did...I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by changeing the http method in laravell.

**from post**

```
Route::post('/xxxxxxxxxx/{id}', [SalaryExportsController::class, 'export']);
```

**to get**

```
Route::get('/xxxxxxxxxx/{id}', [SalaryExportsController::class, 'export']);
```